# Multiple Fragments in One Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

The issue of many fragments in one activity has been covered here before, but I cannot seem to find a solution for my positioning problem.

I want a horizontal scroll bar on top of the screen and under it a custom ListFragment. The code I am posting below puts up the scroll bar and then the ListFragment overwrites it.  When I try to modify the hosting FrameLayout to have two FrameLayouts I get runtime errors.

Simply, How can I position the listFragment under the scrollbar?

```
 public class GoogleNewsMainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

public static Context c;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    c=this;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);


     /* FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

   if (fragment == null) {
        Scroll_Menu_Fragment scrollFragment = new Scroll_Menu_Fragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, scrollFragment)
            .commit();

        GoogleNewsMainFragment f = new GoogleNewsMainFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, f)
            .commit();  

    }  */
}
 }
```

Here is the scroll bar fragment:

```
 public class Scroll_Menu_Fragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.scrollbar_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

 }
```

This is the ListFragment

```
 public class GoogleNewsMainFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public final static String NEWSFROMSERVICE = "NEWSFROMSERVICE";



static ImageView thumbnail;
static String mSectionSelected;
private NewsCursor mCursor;
private ListView lv;

private NewsCursorAdapter adapter;


public static final String ID = "id";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mSectionSelected = "";  // until they select one



    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);




}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_news_main, container, false);

    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.news_list_title);

    return v;
}
```

And finally the hosting layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" > 

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/scrollFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    class="com.gilchrist.android.googlenews.Scroll_Menu_Fragment" ></fragment>

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    class="com.gilchrist.android.googlenews.GoogleNewsMainFragment" ></fragment>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i guess u should be adding the fragments in the xml as well for more info just have look at vogella example on the particular chapter

Comment: I changed the code that was originally posted and put the fragments in the activity layout - as suggested by someone in the comment above.  the idea is to have the scrollview along the top of the screen and the remainder of the screen taken up by a listFragment.  Same problem as I had when I tried to do this in runtime.  The scroll bar appears at the top of the screen and then the listfragment takes up the entire screen and overwrites the scrollbar.   How do you position the two fragments one above the other???

Answer (score 1):

I just updated the activity layout. The problem was caused by the weight values I was using. By going to 90 and 10 I got exactly what I wanted.  All of the code above now works.