# How to display multiple fragments in one activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight

My question is related to this one:

[Multiple Fragments in One Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166556/multiple-fragments-in-one-activity)

I'm displaying three fragments in an activity on a tablet: two only contain text(Ingredients and Steps) and one an Exoplayer and text. All the fragments are enclosed in respective Frame Layouts. I'm using the Constraint Layout as the parent layout. The ExoPlayer isn't uniformly displayed in both portrait and landscape modes due to the length of the text in the Ingredients fragment. It is supposed to always be to the right of that Fragment and above the Steps Fragment. The two other Fragments are displayed properly on the left of the screen.

I thought about using a Linear layout and setting layout weights but then read in several posts that it's not recommended. What is the best way to display the ExoPlayer fragment in this type of layout? Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tablet_detail_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="annin.my.android.bakingapp.ui.IngredientStepsActivity">
        <!--
        This layout is a two-pane layout for the master/detail flow.
        -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/steps_fragment_container"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.4"
            >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ingredients_fragment_container"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.4" >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/steps_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ingredients_fragment_container"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.4"
           >

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: add proper constraints to every frame layout. I see you've missed end constraint of video_fragment_container etc. Constraintlayout won't work perfectly unless all four(start, end, top, bottom) constraints are set for every child.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straightforward, just make 2 fragment and then assign them the respective fragment files like so:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:name="annin.my.android.bakingapp.ui.Fragment1" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment_2"
    android:name="annin.my.android.bakingapp.ui.Fragment2" />
```

Comment: But the fragments are enclosed in the Frame layout instead of <fragment. How can the Exoplayer be displayed uniformly? What should be the parent layout: Constraint, Linear, or Relative?